# Can Upsert be more effective if we have more data?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-delete, upsert

I have to delete some amount of data and insert some into same table.

Will there be any performance improvement if we go for Upsert in a loop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Just use a simple

```
DELETE ...
INSERT ...
```

...probably in a transaction too

You can't "UPSERT" in SQL Server 2005. MERGE was added for SQL Server 2008.

A loop is almost never the answer for any query in a database engine

Comment: I am working inn sql server 2008 (I didnt select it bcoz 2008 is not available in the list).

Comment: @Anish: I have no tested but it's probably the same because still has to do the same combined insert/update/delete